# How many patients have been diagnosed by doctors as having allergies?

Tags: statistics, allergy

This is a followup to another [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32128/what-percentage-of-reported-allergies-are-genuine?noredirect=1#comment62331_32128).

I propose a method of getting an *upper bound* on the number of people who have received a doctor's diagnosis of having an allergy. This would include any form of testing, or no testing -- in other words, if a doctor says "you probably have an allergy" that counts.

Doctors would simply report the count - no personally identifying information. Possibly they already do report this information, in some form or another. Or maybe some U.S. departments keep it in some form?

I say "upper bound" because we accept that some patients are double-counted, but this avoids the privacy concerns of de-duplicating the list.

Comment: What's the purpose of knowing this number?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what significance this information would serve; could you elaborate? (To be clear, I don't think satisfying curiosity is significant.) Who would benefit, and how? Doctors are not required to report allergies; they're not even required to report significant adverse drug-related events (including allergic reactions). Doctors already spend too much time with data input into medical records; it's highly unlikely that a physician would bother to report this unless some significant greater good could be demonstrated (e.g. number of deaths/hospitalizations prevented.)

Comment: The hypothesis is that "I'm allergic" is an inappropriate way of medicalizing simple dislikes or fads. It hurts people who genuinely ARE "allergic" -- e.g. people with Celiac are damaged by those claiming to be allergic to gluten. Someone will discount their legitimate requests. That's the rationale.

Comment: Okay, suppose I'm a doctor and a patient comes to me complaining of symptoms consistent with celiac disease. Thanks to your reporting requirement, I know that 30% of all patients have an allergy to _something_. How would that change my diagnosis or treatment? I think the only way you're getting useful data from this is if you study specific allergies. Lumping everything into one big number (and it would be big) is useless.

Comment: It's not intended for YOU. You would just do your job as you always do.

Comment: Incidentally, the CDC apparently considers it a public health question: what percent of the population has one of their classes of allergies, and they ran this random survey. So this is a cross-check on that. It only asks for aggregate info.

As for Carey Gregory: based on your other comment (since deleted) about cousins and potato salad, you seem to have a personal issue based on some other thread. Maybe you should make that its own question?

Comment: Then who is it intended for? Who would make use of this data? Also, I wasn't the one who made a comment about potato salad and nobody here has any personal issues with your question. Hang around a little longer and learn how SE sites work. You might want to visit the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: I am a doctor (really). It's completely irrelevant to me if people falsely claim to have gluten allergies/other. I will treat the patient in front of me for the problem they present with. What you're asking is time consuming for physicians, costly (in the millions for a database), and of no significant value.  " 'I'm allergic' is an inappropriate way of medicalizing[?] simple dislikes or fads." Why would that matter to me? My job isn't to correct everyone's statements, it's to keep informed and treat patients appropriately.